# Move files whose file name matches 2 patterns in the terminal

Tags: unix, terminal

I need to copy files from a remote server to my local machine whose file names match more than 1 pattern.

For file names that match 1 pattern, the answer can be found here: [enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259744/to-move-all-file-with-certain-common-string-except-the-extension-of-the-file-to). What about files with 2 patterns? I.e. files that contain a string x and a string y? I will be using scp to transfer the files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this :

```
scp host:/path/to/file*pattern1*pattern2* .
```